# I want to add a queue function to MusicBOT with Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am a programming layman. I made a BOT to play songs on `Discord.py`. However, the next song cannot be played automatically.

I want to be able to play the next song when the song is over.Can you tell me how to do it?

```py
    
    import discord

    from discord import FFmpegPCMAudio, PCMVolumeTransformer, AudioSource
    from discord.ext import commands


    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        print('MusicBot Status\nOnline')
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=".help", type=1))

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author.bot:
            return

    @commands.command()
    async def join_voice(self, ctx):
        connected = ctx.author.voice
        if connected:
            await connected.channel.connect() #  Use the channel instance you put into a variable



        @client.event
        async def on_message(message):

        if message.content == (".music1"):
            message.guild.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('music1.mp3'))

        if message.content == (".music1"):
            message.guild.voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('music1.mp3'))

        if message.content == ".join"
            await message.author.voice.channel.connect()

            await message.channel.send("connected.")

        if message.content == (".dis"):
            await message.guild.voice_client.disconnect()

            await message.channel.send("disconnected.")
```